# Which Pokémon cry out their name, and which don't?

Tags: pokemon

In Pokémon, some Pokémon "cries" are their name and some are not.

Is there a list of Pokémon whose cries are their name and Pokémon whose cries aren't?

I did do research but I didn't find the answer I was looking for.

I asked this on [Arcade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/301934/is-there-a-list-somwhere-that), but they told me to ask it here instead.

Comment: @Matt ninja'ed on the edit.

Comment: Welcome to A&M! Would you be able to add a link to your question on Gaming for us? I'm not sure why they'd send it over here if it was the games you were interested in. 
Also, I've altered your question slightly as if it's purely regarding the games it would be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @DrakaSAN Sorry, haha :P Good work on getting the old question though, I've approved your part.

Comment: http://pokecries.com/ may be this will help

Comment: The problem with making such a list will be that we would need to know the japanese name of the pokemon and its pronouciation, check for the cries in game, and the cries in the anime too. With 600+ pokemon now, and cries that changed between generations, it would mean checking at least 6k cries.

Answer (score 5):

Most Pokémon names are a reflection of their cries. This makes sense as the scientific community of the Pokémon universe would have easily coined a common name to the fascinating creatures.

Classic examples of name-cry match are `Pikachu`, `Emolga`, `Cyndaquil`, `Shinx` and `Oshawatt`. `Chatot`, `Mew` and `Ditto` can say a bit more than their own names due to their nature...

Some perfect exceptions to the name-cry rule are `Onyx`, `Gyrados` and `Rotom`. They just seem roar/screech with no clear decipherable word. *Many* bug types seem to have no clear cries.

Actually, there are some which say a part of their name but not completely!
Consider `Pacharisu`, which usually utters "chhipa" most of the times!

Also a few Pokémon communicate through telepathy, such as `Lucario` and `Zorua`... They've never seen crying out their own names.

Finally there are Pokémon which don't have vocal abilities, such as `Staryu` (although it literally sounds like "HYA")

I guess a list has to be manually compiled...

Comment: This is not surprising. In real life, many languages have assigned names to animals this way. Listen to the word for cat in Mandarin Chinese and tell me that it is anything *other* than clear onomatopoeia. Ancient Egyptian did the same thing - writings found in ancient tombs are full of references to *mews*.

Comment: @Robert Hahaha, I googled `cat Mandarin pronunciation`, that was amazing.    Māo Māo Māo!  xD